# Imprimir valores de determinadas claves de un objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs

¿Como hago para obtener o imprimir los datos de un objeto que solo contengan el valor true en ReactJs o JavaScript? Por ejemplo solo quiero imprimir Chino y Japones

```js
subjects {
  Idiomas: {
    Aleman: false,
    Chino: true,
    Espanol: false,
    Frances: false,
    Ingles: false,
    Japones: true,
    Portugues: false,
 }
 Matematicas:{
    masDatos
 }
 etc {
 }
}
```

He intentado con map y filter pero sin exito no se que he estado haciendo mal el objeto Idiomas es uno de varios que se encuentran en otro objeto llamado subjects y he intentado esto:

```
const materiasData = teachers.map((item) => item.subjects); 
const materias = materiasData.filter(i => i === true);
```

Comment: React no deja de ser JavaScript, ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: he intentado con map y filter pero sin exito no se que he estado haciendo mal el objeto Idiomas es uno de varios que se encuentran en otro objeto llamado subjects y he intentado esto: const materiasData = teachers.map((item) => item.subjects);
  const materias = materiasData.filter(i => i === true);

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que has intentado y la estructura dentro de la cual esta este objeto

Comment: Lo que compartes no es un objeto válido. Parece ser un JSON, pero no estamos seguros. Puedes dar mas detalles, o ser mas especifico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con una estructura similar a esta:

```
const subjects = [{
  Idiomas: {
    Aleman: false,
    Chino: true,
    Espanol: false,
    Frances: false,
    Ingles: false,
    Japones: true,
    Portugues: false,
 },
 Matematicas:{
    masDatos: 1
 }
}]
```

Podemos proceder del siguiente modo:

- Extraer el objeto asociado a la clave `Idiomas`, lo hacemos por medio de `map` que nos regresaría un array nuevo con los elementos que cumplan la condición dada.

  ```
    let idiomasElegidos = subjects.map((idioma) => idioma.Idiomas);
  ```
- Como tenemos un array nuevo, entonces primero lo debemos iterar, en este caso lo hacemos por medio del ciclo `for of` así:

  ```
    for(let idioma of idiomasElegidos) {
      console.log(idioma);
    }
  ```
- Ahora que ya pudimos acceder a la estructura del objeto, debemos iterar los elementos que componen al objeto, para este caso `for in`
- En el mismo paso anterior, vamos a verificar por medio de un condicional si el valor asociado a cada clave es `true` y en concencuencia hacer la impresión de los idiomas asociados:

  ```
    for(let idioma of idiomasElegidos) {
      for(let idiomaLista in idioma) {
        if (idioma[idiomaLista]) {
          console.log(idiomaLista);
        }
      }
    }
  ```

El código completo es así:

```js
    const subjects = [{
      Idiomas: {
        Aleman: false,
        Chino: true,
        Espanol: false,
        Frances: false,
        Ingles: false,
        Japones: true,
        Portugues: false,
     },
     Matematicas:{
        masDatos: 1
     }
    }]

    let idiomasElegidos = subjects.map((idioma) => idioma.Idiomas);

    for(let idioma of idiomasElegidos) {
      for(let idiomaLista in idioma) {
        if (idioma[idiomaLista]) {
          console.log(idiomaLista);
        }
      }
    }
```

**Fuentes de referencia**

- [ciclo `for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)
- [ciclo `for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of)
- [método `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)